# "User is unregistered with iMessage" error message

Tags: ipod-touch, ios, messages

I use an iPod 4th gen and I text my boyfriend on iMessage to his iPhone- either his number or email. Everything was all good until it came up with a red exclamation mark, I deleted the conversations to start fresh but then it said he's unregistered with iMessages. But I can still text my other friends, it's just him that I can't.

We talked it over and he can't text me either. I asked one of my friends to text his number and it worked. I've tried rebooting my iPod Touch, restarting it, making multiple ID accounts-only one worked then later failed. This has been happening for 3 weeks and its hasn't recovered. Anyone help me out? I've also tried iMessaging him on 1 iPad and 2 other iPods, but none of those worked.

How can I iMessage him again?

Comment: I'm having the same issues and highly suspect the recent updates 6.1.1 and 6.1.2 as being the culprit. My guess is there will be an additional update to address this subject. Strangely my iPhone will work for the same phone/email addresses that I'm unable to iMessage on my iPad mini and Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the "No longer have your iPhone?" section on https://selfsolve.apple.com/deregister-imessage, then turn it on again on you iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning off iMessage on his devices and then re-activating them. I would suggest doing it on his iPhone first and then the other devices. After activating each device, check to make sure that they are set up to receive at all addresses required.